# Using session variables on php embedded in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i have spent several hours searching about without success, please help me with following:
I have wp exec plugin installed in my fresh wordpress installation.
I can use regular php and mysql queries inside wordpress posts; now i need to use wordpress user session variables to send mysql queries from php scripts in wordpress post.
I mean queries like....... ("select * from table where id_user ='".$_SESSION['ID']."'");

thanks a lot

Diego Jimenez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this standard function to get the user ID and the rest should work:

```
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
```

See [definition](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id)

Comment: Where should this be used? And how should it be used? If a session isn't started, get_current_user_id() will return 0. There are other issues, depending on how and where the SQL query scripts are being executed. This is only a fraction of an answer.